# How does Docker Hub's Automated Build configuration work with Mercurial bookmarks?

Tags: configuration, mercurial, build-automation, dockerhub

Docker Hub's [Automated Build documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#/add-and-run-a-new-build) talks about setting up builds based on branches and tags, but does not mention Mercurial bookmarks or how they interact with the build configuration.

Can you configure automated builds based on Mercurial bookmarks, and have bookmark pushes trigger the builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Configure the bookmark names as if they were tags, and it should work.

Longer answer: From some experimentation, as of Sep. 2016, it seems that bookmark names actually match against both tag *and* branch builds configured in Docker Hub. However, when pushing a bookmark update, only **tag** builds matching the name will get triggered automatically; **branch** builds won't get triggered automatically, but can still be triggered manually.